# How to grep the output of youtube-dl?

Tags: grep, youtube-dl

The normal output for youtube-dl is the following

```
[download] Downloading video #3 of 33
[youtube] WbWb0u8bJrU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] WbWb0u8bJrU: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] WbWb0u8bJrU: Extracting video information
[download] Resuming download at byte 107919109
[download] Destination: Lec 6.mp4
[download]  86.2% of 137.18MiB at 48.80KiB/s ETA 06:37
```

I need to show the first and last monitor the downloading I use the command

```
 youtube-dl -cit -f 18 URL | grep -e ETA -e "Downloading video #"
```

It's not working only the first line is working while the last line is not, and I see the download is running  as the file size grows

Comment: did you want to see only the last line from the running output? I mean `[download]  11.2% of 13.33MiB at  8.40KiB/s ETA 24:03` line only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to get just the last line.

To do this, simply add the `--newline` flag to `youtube-dl`.

```
youtube-dl --newline -cit -f 18 URL | grep -e ETA -e "Downloading video #"
```

This causes the progress to be output to a new line each time, rather than continually erasing and deleting parts of the same line. This is required for your grep command to work.

Comment: many thanks for the answer it did what i need ,but is there a way to show only one line of the output

Comment: That would be a bit trickier. You would have to delete the previous line before printing the current line. I know how to do it in Python, but it would be a much longer script. You could probably do it in bash by piping the output of the above command to a command which prints a delete character. However, I've had a quick go at this and I can't quite get it right.